# UnityIAP Android Failed Purchase NoConsumible

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a system to made android in-app purchasing. If I use one device I'm able to integrate the system well, When user buy a noConsumible item and reinstall app this item was given.

The problem become when use other device with same account. When made purchase in some device, the other can't detect the purchase on relaunch or reinstall the app, and show the next message "Item was already owned", but I can't catch this error and give the item.

- Steps to follow:

  1. Install app on device A
  2. Buy a No Consumible Item on device A
  3. Install app on deice B
  4. Check item No Consumible was give on device B
  5. Buy a No Consumible Item on device B
  6. Relaunch app on device A
  7. Check item No Consumible wasn't give on device A

Code:

```
   private void initializeUnityIAP()
{
    if (IStoreListener != null && IStoreListener.IsUnityIAPInicialized())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Create a builder, first passing in a suite of Unity provided stores.
    var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
    //Configure google play
    builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().SetPublicKey(GOOGLE_PLAY_KEY);

    // Adding currency pack
    foreach (VirtualCurrencyPack currencyPack in storeAssets.packs)
    {
        builder.AddProduct(currencyPack.id, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs() {
            { currencyPack.id, AppleAppStore.Name },
            { currencyPack.id, GooglePlay.Name },
        });
    }

    // Adding offers
    foreach (VirtualOffer virtualOffer in storeAssets.offers)
    {
        builder.AddProduct(virtualOffer.id, ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs() {
            { virtualOffer.id, AppleAppStore.Name },
            { virtualOffer.id, GooglePlay.Name },
        });
    }

    IStoreListener = new AxesBillingStoreListener();
    UnityPurchasing.Initialize(IStoreListener, builder);
}



public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
{
    m_StoreController = controller;
    m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;


    foreach (var item in controller.products.all)
    {
        //Product is available
        if (item.availableToPurchase)
        {
            // Update definition data product
            AxesBillingManager.instance.GetElementById(item.definition.id).purchaseType.amount = (double)(item.metadata.localizedPrice);
            AxesBillingManager.instance.GetElementById(item.definition.id).purchaseType.currencyCode = item.metadata.isoCurrencyCode;

            // Product was purchase
            if (item.hasReceipt)
            {
                VirtualObject element = AxesBillingManager.instance.GetElementById(item.definition.id);
                element.Give(element.amountToGive);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Product is not available in store
            AxesBillingManager.instance.GetElementById(item.definition.id).isAvailableInGoogleStore = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The application was published in the store?

Comment: Please post your Unity IAP code.

Comment: @RichJoslin I Edit my ask writting the code used